# "The place under the bed" is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

My brother was sweeping the house the other day, and I asked him:

> Have you already swept **the place under the bed?**

As a learner I didn't find any other alternative to talk about **the place / space under the bed.**

How would native speakers say this?

Answer (score 4):

I would say it's not wrong, *the place* is describing a location that, in this context, was identified by its relation with the bed. However, it isn't seem to bring significant meaning when added in the sentence.

Thus, just:

> Have you already swept under the bed?

or maybe

> Have you already swept *the floor* under the bed?

could express the same idea and, even to me, it sounds better in the ears